# Azure application gateway overwrites custom health probe

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

As Azure Application Gateway doesn't support http basic authentication and throws 502 error when I try to reach my app in kubernetes, I've added custom settings to health probe (treat 401 error as healthy). Everything works fine, however my setting are being overwritten after some time. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: hey jmich were you able to resolve this?
im facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AKS with the Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC)? AGIC is an AKS pod that manages ingress. When AKS + AGIC is configured, it has full ownership over the Application Gateway. Meaning, when you make a change to the AppGW manually (such as updated health probe status code), AGIC has the authority to remove the manual change and revert to the original config.

To get around this, you need to use AGIC to configure the health probe acceptable status code using annotations. See this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-annotations?source=recommendations). The doc doesn't have the health probe status code annotation listed but I think you can use:

`appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-status-codes: "200-401"`

If you are NOT using AKS + AGIC, there is more than likely some other automation overwriting your changes to the health probe. I'd recommend reviewing the Application Gateway Activity Log to see what/who is reverting your change. More info on reviewing activity logs at this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/change-history-report).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Additionally there's this [doc](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/#health-probe-status-codes)

Comment: Just an update in 2023, that annotation no longer exists